# Read a last line containing string in a text file?

Tags: c#

i have a text file:

```
ABCD - 11111
111212
13121


ABCD - 1213
12312
34534


ABCD - 21312
123123
123123
```

How do i to read from last line start with 'ABCD' to end of file. In the above example, result is:

```
ABCD - 21312
123123
123123
```

Comment: If you know the content of the file then it is possible, u can use any conditions for check that data, can u show how u proceed, i mean your work code

Comment: You can read the file into a string and use `i = s.LastIndexOf("ABCD")` and then SubString from i to the end of string

Comment: Is your file going be big? Would you need to remove those last three lines from your file after reading them?

Comment: @Alex: thank you for your reply. But my file not too big, usually ~100 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the file into a `string`, you can accomplish this by using `Substring` and `LastIndexOf`.

```
string inputText = "ABCD - 11111\n111212\n13121\n\n\n" +
                   "ABCD - 1213\n12312\n34534\n\n\nABCD - 21312\n123123\n123123";
string remainingText = inputText.Substring(inputText.LastIndexOf("ABCD"));
```

`LastIndexOf` will determine the last index where the string `ABCD` occurs (in this case, 54).

`Substring` will then remove all text occurring before that index to give you the result you expect.

Therefore `remainingText` will contain the value:

```
ABCD - 21312\n123123\n123123
```

Answer (score 0):

First read the file into an string then use LastIndexOf("ABCD") to find the position of last occurrence of your pattern and finally use SubString to extract it.

```
 string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt"; 
 string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
 int position = readText.LastIndexOf("ABCD");
 string toEnd = readText.Substring(position ,readText.Length - position).
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the System.IO namespace's method File.ReasAllText will read the content of the txt file. Assign the value to string variable.

```
File.ReadAllText("sample.txt");
```

Then find the last occurrence of the string ABCD

```
// Find the last occurrence of ABCD.
int index = sString.LastIndexOf('ABCD');
```

Then using substring get the string value from last index.

```
 string subStr = sString.Substring(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some performance or efficiency I wouldn't read the entire file into memory (especially if it is going to be big). I would use FileStreams with Seek method to start reading from the end of the file last three lines. The exact implementation depends of your data format. In case you don't have a strict format of last three lines then read from the end byte per byte until you read three new lines. Of course the code is not so simple but you gain the best efficiency.